# Different parameters’ values for different time intervals in deSolve

Tags: r

I am trying to solve a SVEIR (susceptible, vaccinated, exposed, infected and removed) model using deSolve. The outbreak begins on the 8th day (by importing an index case in the susceptible population). For capturing this I make use of an event (by adding the value one (1) to the state variable (I) in time t=8.

```
# Model's parameters

parms <- c(beta=1.29, 
       betaE=0.25, 
       betaI=1, 
       betaV=0.0, 
       sigma=0.5, 
       gama=0.2, 
       delta=1/365, 
       m=0.000046, 
       r=0.000052, 
       kapa=1.857/10000,            
       alpha=0.00643, 
       thita=1/365, 
       f=0.002)    
dt    <- seq(0,50,0.25)      

inits <- c(S=14900, V=0, E=0, I=0, R=0)    
N <- sum(inits)

eventdat <- data.frame(var = c("I"),time = c(8), 
                    value = c(1), method = c("add"))
eventdat

#The SVEIR model

SVEIR <- function(t, x, parms){

with(as.list(c(parms,x)),{
dS <- - beta*betaE*E*(S/N) - beta*betaI*I*(S/N) -  f*S - m*S +delta*R + thita*V + r*N
dV <- - beta*betaE*betaV*E*(V/N) - beta*betaI*betaV*I*(V/N) - m*V - thita*V + f*S
dE <- + beta*betaE*E*(S/N) + beta*betaI*I*(S/N) + beta*betaE*betaV*E*(V/N) + beta*betaI*betaV*I*(V/N) - (m + kapa + sigma)*E
dI <- + sigma*E - (m + alpha + gama)*I
dR <- kapa*E + gama*I - m*R - delta*R       
der <- c(dS, dV, dE, dI, dR)
list(der)      
})

} 

library(deSolve)

out <- as.data.frame(lsoda(inits, dt, SVEIR, parms=parms, events = list(data = eventdat))) 

# Plotting the output

attach(out)

matplot(x = out[,1], y = out[,-1], type = "l", lwd = 2,
    lty = "solid", col = c("red", "blue", "black", "green", "darkgreen"),
    xlab = "time", ylab = "y", main = "SVEIR model")

legend("bottomright", col = c("red", "blue", "black", "green", "darkgreen"),
   legend = c("S", "V", "E", "I", "R"), lwd = 2)
```

Apart from that, I want my model to also **capture changes in some of the parameters**. So, I have been trying (unsuccessfully so far) to integrate within my function a “while” or “for” loop which takes into account the following:

1. for the time period between 0 – 9 I need the value of the parameter
   betaV to be 0
2. for the time period between 10 – 50 I need the value of
   the parameter betaV to be 0.002

I have tried to use an event but R gives me an error (I guess I can make use of an event only for the variables and not for the parameters).

Any idea how a can handle this??

Thanks a lot,

Tom

PS: The model is based on the work of (Samsuzzoha et. al., 2012).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your basic question seems to be how to specify two different values of `betaV` depending on time. Can't you do this in the function, as:

```
#The SVEIR model
SVEIR <- function(t, x, parms){ 
  with(as.list(c(parms,x)),{
    betaV <- ifelse(t<10,betaV,0.002)  # adjust betaV based on value of t
    dS <- - beta*betaE*E*(S/N) - beta*betaI*I*(S/N) -  f*S - m*S +delta*R + thita*V + r*N
    dV <- - beta*betaE*betaV*E*(V/N) - beta*betaI*betaV*I*(V/N) - m*V - thita*V + f*S
    dE <- + beta*betaE*E*(S/N) + beta*betaI*I*(S/N) + beta*betaE*betaV*E*(V/N) + beta*betaI*betaV*I*(V/N) - (m + kapa + sigma)*E
    dI <- + sigma*E - (m + alpha + gama)*I
    dR <- kapa*E + gama*I - m*R - delta*R       
    der <- c(dS, dV, dE, dI, dR)
    list(der)      
  })
```

Note that your question does not actually specify a value for `betaV` on `9 < t < 10`, so I assumed the cutoff at 10.

When I run this with `betaV = 0.002 (t>10)`, there is no discern able difference in the output. If I set `betaV` to 1 or 10 for `t > 10`, `V(t)` is supressed for large `t` and `S, E, I and R` are shifted to lower time. Does this sound right?

Comment: Dear jlhoward,
It works great now. 
You are also right (with respect to the cutoff at 10). 
Thank you very much for your valuable help.
Best regards,
Tom