# Delay changing parameter value after threshold is passed in R ODE model

Tags: r, ode, eventtrigger, timedelay

I am solving a set of ODEs in R and am getting stuck on two things:

1. Changing a parameter (*m*) once a set amount of time has passed (*delay*) after the variable (*D*) crosses a threshold (*D_T*).
2. Returning an array of the parameter values so I can double check it is changing at the correct time.

I am currently using deSolve, but am wondering if I need to write my own ode solver. I have looked at [Different parameters’ values for different time intervals in deSolve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20693586/different-parameters-values-for-different-time-intervals-in-desolve), but it (1) changes the parameter value at a predetermined time, as opposed to when a value being solved for in the ODE model crosses a threshold and (2) does not have the time delay component.

Here is my code so far without the time delay :

```
# define parameters 
P <- c(m_0 = 10,
       R_1 = 0.5, 
       R_2 = 0.1,  
       D_0 = 50,         
       D_T = 5,
       delay = 3
) 
# set initial values 
y_0 <- c(D = 0, m=10)

# set timesteps
times <- seq(0, 100, length = 101) 

# define function   
bit <- function(t,y,parms){
  with(as.list(c(parms,y)),{

    m <- ifelse(D >= D_T, m_0 *.68, m_0)  

    dD <- D_0 * (R_1 / (R_1 - R_2)) * (-R_2 * exp(-R_2 * t) + R_1 * exp(-R_1 * t)) 

    res <- c(dD, m)
    list(res)
  })
}


# Solve model
library(deSolve)
out <- ode(y = y_0, times = times, func = bit, parms = P)
out.df <- as.data.frame(out)
```

One problem is *m* increases with each time unit. It should only be 10 (when below the threshold) or 6.8 (when above the threshold). Is it being treated as an ODE since I included it in the initial conditions vector and returned derivatives vector? How else can you check on variables within a function while using deSolve?

With regards to the time delay, I have thought about something like below, but it is not working either. *m* constantly increases and there does not appear to be any time delay:

```
if (D >= D_T){
      T_start = t + delay
      while (t > T_start){
        m <- 0.68 * m_0
      }
    }
```

Thanks in advance. I appreciate any advice you may have.

**Update**

I think what I am looking for is event handling with a time delay, as opposed to just a timelag.

To clarify, D is a drug concentration. In the event that D rises above the threshold (D_T), m will be set to a new value, but after a short time delay. Similarly, when D falls below D_T, m will be reset to its original value after the same delay period. The closest example so far is the ball bouncing problem on p. 25: < https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/deSolve/vignettes/deSolve.pdf > . It doesn't have the time component though. Perhaps I need multiple events (one where the concentration triggers the start of the timer, another where the timer triggers the change in m)? For instance:

```
event1 <- function(t,y,parms){
  difference <- D - D_T
  difference <- 0  # when D = D_T, trigger event 1
  Timer <- delay   # countdown for delay
}
event2 <- function (t,y,parms) {
    Timer <- 0     # when delay is over, trigger event 2
    m <- m*0.68    # new m value 
}

# solve ode by calling function and relevant events
out <- ode(func = bit, y = y_0, times = times, parms = P, + event1 + event2)
```

Is there a more compact way to do this? Currently, I'd have to write another 2 events to capture the change for when D falls below D_T again. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're super close! As you suspected, you're treating `m` as a variable in your ODE. So, take it out of your initial conditions. You can still return it from your function as an element of the list, as shown below. Regarding the delay, use `dede` instead of `ode`. You'll also need the `lagvalue` function to access previous values of your state variable. Stick that all together and you get this.

```
# define parameters 
P <- c(m_0 = 10,
       R_1 = 0.5, 
       R_2 = 0.1,  
       D_0 = 50,         
       D_T = 5,
       delay = 3
) 
# set initial values 
y_0 <- c(D = 0)

# set timesteps
times <- seq(0, 100, length = 101) 

# define function   
bit <- function(t,y,parms){
  with(as.list(c(parms,y)),{

    if(t>delay){
      m <- ifelse(lagvalue(t-delay) >= D_T, m_0 *.68, m_0)  
    }else{
      m <- m_0
    }

    dD <- D_0 * (R_1 / (R_1 - R_2)) * (-R_2 * exp(-R_2 * t) + R_1 * exp(-R_1 * t)) 

    list(dD, m = m)
  })
}


# Solve model
library(deSolve)
out <- dede(y = y_0, times = times, func = bit, parms = P)
out.df <- as.data.frame(out)
```

which produces

```
    time            D    m
1      0  0.000000000 10.0
2      1 18.644171500 10.0
3      2 28.178200649 10.0
4      3 32.355497453 10.0
5      4 33.436541140  6.8
6      5 32.777847256  6.8
7      6 31.189028116  6.8
8      7 29.149237619  6.8
9      8 26.938325140  6.8
10     9 24.716283542  6.8
11    10 22.571335485  6.8
12    11 20.549011615  6.8
13    12 18.669708334  6.8
14    13 16.939264216  6.8
15    14 15.355309725  6.8
16    15 13.911059339  6.8
17    16 12.597558070  6.8
18    17 11.404995591  6.8
19    18 10.323459512  6.8
20    19  9.343352574  6.8
21    20  8.455609818  6.8
22    21  7.651797850  6.8
23    22  6.924145655  6.8
24    23  6.265536717  6.8
25    24  5.669480182  6.8
26    25  5.130071613  6.8
27    26  4.641949483  6.8
28    27  4.200250976  6.8
29    28  3.800569059  6.8
30    29  3.438911847 10.0
31    30  3.111664769 10.0
32    31  2.815555669 10.0
33    32  2.547622830 10.0
34    33  2.305185812 10.0
35    34  2.085818900 10.0
36    35  1.887327010 10.0
37    36  1.707723816 10.0
38    37  1.545211942 10.0
39    38  1.398165006 10.0
40    39  1.265111368 10.0
41    40  1.144719417 10.0
42    41  1.035784250 10.0
43    42  0.937215619 10.0
44    43  0.848027025 10.0
45    44  0.767325842 10.0
46    45  0.694304388 10.0
47    46  0.628231843 10.0
48    47  0.568446930 10.0
49    48  0.514351303 10.0
50    49  0.465403556 10.0
51    50  0.421113802 10.0
52    51  0.381038775 10.0
53    52  0.344777391 10.0
54    53  0.311966734 10.0
55    54  0.282278424 10.0
56    55  0.255415330 10.0
57    56  0.231108597 10.0
58    57  0.209114956 10.0
59    58  0.189214287 10.0
60    59  0.171207416 10.0
61    60  0.154914126 10.0
62    61  0.140171348 10.0
63    62  0.126831530 10.0
64    63  0.114761164 10.0
65    64  0.103839445 10.0
66    65  0.093957065 10.0
67    66  0.085015117 10.0
68    67  0.076924109 10.0
69    68  0.069603062 10.0
70    69  0.062978704 10.0
71    70  0.056984738 10.0
72    71  0.051561173 10.0
73    72  0.046653728 10.0
74    73  0.042213289 10.0
75    74  0.038195413 10.0
76    75  0.034559888 10.0
77    76  0.031270330 10.0
78    77  0.028293814 10.0
79    78  0.025600551 10.0
80    79  0.023163586 10.0
81    80  0.020958529 10.0
82    81  0.018963311 10.0
83    82  0.017157963 10.0
84    83  0.015524416 10.0
85    84  0.014046322 10.0
86    85  0.012708888 10.0
87    86  0.011498727 10.0
88    87  0.010403728 10.0
89    88  0.009412932 10.0
90    89  0.008516422 10.0
91    90  0.007705227 10.0
92    91  0.006971228 10.0
93    92  0.006307077 10.0
94    93  0.005706129 10.0
95    94  0.005162369 10.0
96    95  0.004670354 10.0
97    96  0.004225161 10.0
98    97  0.003822333 10.0
99    98  0.003457839 10.0
100   99  0.003128032 10.0
101  100  0.002829610 10.0
```

Notice the delay in switching `m` between 26 and 29, as required.

Comment: Thank you @Lyngbakr. After searching, I think I am looking for is event handling with a time delay, as opposed to a timelag. To clarify, D is a drug concentration. In the event that D rises about the threshold (D_T), m will be set to a new value, but after a short time delay. Similarly, when D falls below D_T, m will be reset to its original value after the same delay period. The closest example so far is the ball bouncing problem on p. 25: [link] (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/deSolve/vignettes/deSolve.pdf). It doesn't have the time component though. Perhaps I need multiple events?